# ANTLR3 - How to get the text of repeating token

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I am using ANTLR3 C version, the grammar snippet is like this:

```
a_cmd : sub_cmd+  'abc'  (sub_cmd)?
       ;
```

Now I need to get the whole text of all the first sub_cmd, the repeated one. I tried doing this:

```
a_cmd : (sc1=(sub_cmd+))  'abc'  (sub_cmd)? 
        {add_text($sc1.$text)}
       ;
```

But I get compile error from gcc:

```
request for member 'ctx' in 'sc1', which is of non-class type 'ANTLR3_COMMON_TOKEN_struct*'
```

So what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Says sc1 is for type ANTLR3_COMMON_TOKEN_struct*

You can use
{ add_text( $sc1->toString() ) }

See for details, http://www.antlr3.org/api/C/struct_a_n_t_l_r3___c_o_m_m_o_n___t_o_k_e_n__struct.html

Comment: I need to change to add_text($sc1->toString($sc1) in order to compile, but the code crashes at the line generated from this, the reason is "sc1" is null even though I can see there is match.